# How to detect textfield cleared all texts?

Tags: uitextfield, ios8.1

I am calling some function when a text field changing text. And I need to call to another function if `UItextfield` get empty while deleting texts one by one. How can I check I  have deleted all the texts. I want to call that function as soon as deleted the last letter (first letter of the sentence that means the letter I typed first time). How can I detect I have deleted the letter I typed first time. (textfield is empty after deleting this letter)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Im having trouble following the question, but i believe you just right click the box on the storyboard, and make a "sent event" for the changing of its value (The last option listed in that category).  From there it would be easy to do what you want with the information currently being displayed in it. You could do:

```
    if (!self.textfield.text.length)
    {
      //desired code to be run in the instance of no text
    }
```